# Azure Functions Storage Queue configuration not working

Tags: azure-functions, azure-storage-queues

I'm trying to set `maxDequeueCount` to 1, but it just doesn't work.
I tried:

```
// host.json
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "extensions": {
    "queues": {
      "maxPollingInterval": "00:00:02",
      "visibilityTimeout": "00:00:30",
      "batchSize": 1,
      "maxDequeueCount": 1,
      "newBatchThreshold": 1,
      "messageEncoding": "base64"
    }
  }
}
```

And I also tried these settings (all 4 variants):

```
// local.settings.json
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    //"AzureFunctionsJobHost__extensions__queues__maxDequeueCount": 1,
    //"AzureFunctionsJobHost__extensions__queues__maxDequeueCount": "1",
    //"AzureFunctionsJobHost__Extensions__Queues__MaxDequeueCount": 1,
    "AzureFunctionsJobHost__Extensions__Queues__MaxDequeueCount": "1",
  }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Function code:

```
        [FunctionName("QueueTriggerTest")]
        public void Run([QueueTrigger("test", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")] string myQueueItem, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Queue trigger function processed: {myQueueItem}");
        }
```

Comment: Could you please provide the function code you're using?

Comment: @HariKrishna Updated the question with the function code, but I don't think it's too relevant.

Answer (score 0):

***Check the below steps to Configure Storage Queue in Azure Functions.***

While creating Azure Function `Queue Trigger`  we need to provide the `Queue name`.

It has to be same as the `Queue` name from the `Azure Portal` => `Storage Account`=> `Queue`

[image]

[image]

- Select the Azure Storage Account.

[image]

- Add the Storage Account connection string from `Storage Account` => `Access Keys`.

[image]

My `host.json`:

```cs
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      }
    }
  },
  "extensions": {
    "queues": {
      "maxPollingInterval": "00:00:02",
      "visibilityTimeout": "00:00:30",
      "batchSize": 1,
      "maxDequeueCount": 2,
      "newBatchThreshold": 1,
      "messageEncoding": "base64"
    }
  }
}
```

***local.settings.json:***

```cs
{
    "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
    "ConnectionQueue": "DefaultEndpointsProtocol=https;AccountName=harshithasa;AccountKey=****;EndpointSuffix=core.windows.net"
  }
}
```

***Function1.cs:***

```cs
using System;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FunctionApp1
{
    public class Function1
    {
        [FunctionName("Function1")]
        public void Run([QueueTrigger("harshuqueue", Connection = "ConnectionQueue")]string myQueueItem, ILogger log)
        {
            log.LogInformation($"C# Queue trigger function processed: {myQueueItem}");

            throw new Exception("Test Exception");
        }
    }
}
```

- Place break point on the `QueueTrigger` function and Run the Application.
- Now, add a message to the queue in the Storage Account and save.
- You can see the breakpoint has hit the created Que Trigger Function.

[image]

[image]

***Output:***

[image]

- If the Queue Trigger successfully process the message, the message gets deleted in the Queue.

[image]

- The use of `maxDequeueCount` is , whenever an exception occurs the message is not processed and will be in the queue only.
- The exception message will be logged as many times as the count of  `maxDequeueCount`.

***Example:***

Iam setting the `maxDequeueCount` to 2 and raising an exception.

- Once the message execution count reaches the `MaxDequeueCount`,   the message will be sent to `Queue poison`.

[image]

Comment: Okay, so what I need is `batchSize` actually, but still not working. I have batchSize = 1, but all the messages are processed in the same time

Answer (score 0):

I found a nasty workaround until I find the correct solution / bug is fixed.

I created 2 queues, queueA & queueB, and a static boolean locker. 
I insert all messages in both of the queues. 
I have a Queue trigger linked to queueA which will start and do the logic: if locker == true, return; else, lock = true (lock), process all messages from queueB, and then locker = false (unlock)

```
        [FunctionName("QueueTrigger")]
        public async Task Run([QueueTrigger("queueA", Connection = "AzureWebJobsStorage")] string message, ILogger log)
        {
            if(_storageQueueService.isFifoLockerActive())
            {
                return;
            }

            _storageQueueService.activateFifoLocker();

            do
            {
                int queueLength = _storageQueueService.GetQueueLength("queueB);

                if (queueLength == 0)
                {
                    break;
                }

                for (int i = 0; i < queueLength; i++)
                {
                    string newMessage = _storageQueueService.DequeueFirstMessage("queueB);
                    // process newMessage...
                }
            } while (true);

            _storageQueueService.deactivateFifoLocker();
        }
```